# Sharing laptop network connection to Pi0W over USB

Tags: raspbian, networking, usb, pi-zero, pi-zero-w

I have already looked at the other posts on this topic however none of them seem to work. I have a raspberry Pi0W, running the latest Raspbian stretch lite (2017-09-07), connected to my laptop over USB and would like to be able to connect to the internet on the pi (to run updates and install packages). (My laptop is running windows 10)

I can ssh into the pi (using PUTTY and the address raspberrypi.local) but even after sharing my connection (rebooting both) or bridging the connection (and rebooting) I still can not connect to the internet.

Running 'ifconfig -a' gives:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 20  bytes 1692 (1.6 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 20  bytes 1692 (1.6 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.7.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.7.255
    inet6 fe80::8494:8eff:fe65:f260  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 86:94:8e:65:f2:60  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 149  bytes 15409 (15.0 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 90  bytes 16921 (16.5 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether b8:27:eb:cf:5d:39  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And running 'sudo route -n' gives:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.7.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 usb0
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 usb0
```

and when I run 'ping www.google.com':

```
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

As for my laptop, I have updated the RNDIS drivers and want to allow the Ethernet connection (USB to pi) to access my Wifi Connection (wifi to my router). I have not changed much in the way of configuration other than the sharing tab of my wifi and when I tried to bridge the connections (I deleted the network bridge afterwards).

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I hope is is just me being silly and missing something, thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem isn't with the configuration on the pi; *everything above is correct.*  The problem is with the configuration **on your laptop**, about which you've said nothing.

Comment: goldilocks Ill edit it in